# How to solve a nonhomogeneous Cauchy-Euler differential equation without using Wronskians

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I need to solve the non-homogenous Cauchy-Euler differential equation

$x^2y''-4xy'+6y=3x$

for class, but we haven't learned anything about Wronskians and that's mentioned in every explaination I see for how to do these problems. Is there a way to solve this without using Wronskians?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$x^2y''-4xy'+6y=3x$$
For the inhomogeneous part, try:
$$y_p=Ax$$
Plug this in the differential equation and find the constant A. Then the solution is:
$$y=y_h+y_p$$
Where $y_h$ is the solution of the homogeneous equation:
$$x^2y''-4xy'+6y=0$$

Comment: thanks, this worked. would this method also work if the right hand side were something more complicated, such as sec^3 (x)?

Comment: No it wont work  it works for this DE @Sylvie

Comment: okay, thank you

Comment: You're welcome @Sylvie